# Small keyboard/keys for kid with little hands that want to learn touch typing

Tags: keyboards

My little kid wants to learn touch typing, but has little hands (7yo). The letters-zone in regular keyboard is too big.

I'm searching for pc USB keyboard, with regular keys layout, preferably full one (104 keys), that is smaller than the standard one, by 10/20/30 percent. I don't care if it's mechanical or not. And I don't need specific printed language (or print at all).

I couldn't find one in AliExpress nor in any other internet store. Are there any? Recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some. The trick is not to search small/mini keyboards, but to specify size: 10 inch keyboard, or 9/8/7 inch. There are some variaty, e.g.: [this](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005002710390758.html), [this](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005003964778642.html), and [this](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005001325887607.html).

About the size: The centeral keyboard part (from tab/shift/control to the backsapce/enter/shift) of normal keyboard is about 11inch. And the small ones come basically in those sizes: ~10inch, ~9inch, and ~7.8inch.

Important to check before buying: Not all of the keyboards conatin function keys. Also, not all of them conatin tiny-bumps on "F" and "J" keys, and those are important for touch typing. Lastly, not all keyboards support PCs (but most of them do).